# Is it possible to hide long comments within the editor?

Tags: comments

LyX has a great feature of being able to hide the content of comments from the editor, leaving only a mark that there's a comment at that area.
I'm now trying to write directly in Latex rather than Lyx. Are there any Latex editors with a similar feature?

Some more details: I have been using the comment environment for long comments. However, I don't want the comment to take up so much space while editing the file as it interferes with navigating - it takes too long to move past all the comments. 
I also don't want to move it to the end of the file or another file, since I want the comments in the relevant place of the file. I want the editor to show something that tells me there's a comment there, which I can expand if I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AucTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), which is a TeX mode for Emacs (not the default mode that comes with Emacs), has functionality for *folding* parts of the buffer, for example comments. At https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Folding.html#Folding you can read about that. When activated you can for example use `C-c C-o C-c` to hide a comment are looking at. It will then be shown just as *%...* until you position yourself inside of it. And if you do the command for folding an environment inside of `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` only *[comment]* will be seen until you position yourself inside.

Answer (score 0):

Some generic programmers' text editors will allow you to fold up sections demarcated in some way.  I can do this in jEdit (cross platform) for example:

```
\comment{still need to add an intro%{{{
this is some text
over many lines}
%}}}
```

and if I click on the line number next to the first line of this I can toggle between the display above and

```
\comment{still need to add an intro%{{{ [3 lines]
```

where `%{{{`...`%}}}` is an "explicit fold" . I can do the same in Python in the same editor.

LaTeX support isn't integrated but there's a macro suite out there somewhere if you want it -- I used about 3 of the buttons in the macro while writing my thesis and don't bother using any more.

You can do all the same things on Notepad++ on windows as well.  I have a general preference for using the same editor for code and LaTeX, and for an editor with generic features and extensibility.  This doesn't suit everyone.

This was going to be a comment (probably still should be but for formatting).